# Given area of quadrilateral find missing coordinates

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, coordinate-systems, quadrilateral

[image]

Can someone please explain how to proceed with this question, or maybe give me hints as to how to do it? I am not familiar with concave polygons at all, so any help with that as well would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is 18.5 the sum of the area of both quadrilaterals or is it the area of them both minus any overlap?

Comment: It's referring to 2 distinct quadrilaterals, each of which have an area of 18.5. The only difference is the y coordinate of D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join diagonal AC. Your quadrilateral will get divided into two triangles ABC , ADC. Find area of triangle ABC using Heron's formula. Then find value is ADC . So area of ADC is 13.5. you know AC is √50 so find the corresponding height of triangle which will come out  to be 27/√50.

Now find the eq of line AC and use the formula for finding distance of point D from AC and equate it with 27/√50.

Now A(5,-2);C(-2,-3). So slope of line AC =-2+3/5+2=1/7.

y+3/x+2=1/7

Which will give you eq 
x-7y-19=0

Now according to the formula of distance of a point from line 
27/√50=|a(x1)+b(y1)+c|/√(a^2+b^2)
             =|1×-1+-7×k-19|/√49+1
             =.| -7k-20| /√50
|-7k-20|=27

-7k-20= 27 or -27

-7k-20=27
k=47/-7= -47/7

-7k-20=-27
k=-7/-7=1

You will get value of k as 1 and -329/49

1+(-47/7)=-40/7

Comment: I have the area of both triangles, ADC=15.5, but how does that help me find k unless I do a ridiculously complicated equation using Heron's formula and k=15.5. Is this what you're referring to by quadratic equation or do you have a different equation?

Comment: Correction I meant to put ADC= 13.5

Comment: Sorry I thought it can be done for ADC too using Heron's. I am editing it to show another method.

Comment: I have edited it i an really sorry for the first mistake. Hope you get it now. Your answer of k is 1, -329/49. So it's sum is -280/49= -40/7

Comment: Did you get it?

Comment: I see and understand your logic there, but the correct answer is -60/7, the answers for these things are rarely incorrect too, maybe a simple mistake in your math?

Comment: I rechecked it i am getting the same answer. Did you try? What answer did you get?

Comment: Yeah, this question is from a regional high school math contest, and the only way a wrong answer would be corrected is if someone protested it, but seeing as probably little to no one got it correct it probably wasn't protested, so I wouldn't be surprised if -40/7 is correct.

Comment: Did you verify it ?

Comment: No real way to verify it other than post it here honestly, according to both you and @quazi 's logic, which appears to be correct, which I have checked, the answer is -40/7

Comment: Ok fine i will post complete solution.

Comment: Are you satisfied now.

Comment: If you are please accept☺️

Answer (score 0):

Let $D_1$ be the required point for which the specified quadrilateral is convex.

Let $D_2$ be the required point for which the specified quadrilateral is concave.

Then $\text{area}(AD_1CB) = \text{area}(ABCD_2) = {\displaystyle{\frac{37}{2}}}$.

For this problem, it's natural to apply the Surveyor's Formula . . .

[image]

First, we get the area of quadrilateral $AD_1CB$:

$\text{}$
\begin{align*}
\text{area}(AD_1CB)&=
\small{
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\left|
\begin{matrix}
5 & -1\\
-2 & k\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
-1 & -2\\
k & -3\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
-2 & 1\\
-3 & -4\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
1 & 5\\
-4 & -2\\
\end{matrix}
\right|
\right)
}
\\[6pt]
&= 
{\small{
\frac{1}{2}}}
\bigg(
(5k-2)+
(3+2k)+
(11)+
(18)
\bigg)
\\[6pt]
&= 
{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}
\left(7k + 30\right)
\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
&\text{area}(AD_1CB) = \frac{37}{2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\\[6pt]
\implies\; &{\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\left(7k + 30\right) =\frac{37}{2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\\[6pt]
\implies\; &k = 1\\[6pt]
\implies\; &D_1 = (-1,1)
\end{align*}

$\text{}$
Next, we get the area of quadrilateral $ABCD_2$:

$\text{}$

\begin{align*}
\text{area}(ABCD_2)
&=
\small{
\frac{1}{2}
\left(
\left|
\begin{matrix}
5 & 1\\
-2 & -4\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
1 & -2\\
-4 & -3\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
-2 & -1\\
-3 & k\\
\end{matrix}
\right|+
\left|
\begin{matrix}
-1 & 5\\
k & -2\\
\end{matrix}
\right|
\right)
}
\\[6pt]
&= 
{\small{
\frac{1}{2}}}
\bigg(
(-18)+
(-11)+
(-2k - 3)+
(2-5k)
\bigg)
\\[6pt]
&=
{\small{-\frac{1}{2}}}
\left(7k + 30\right)
\\[6pt]
\end{align*}

Then

\begin{align*}
&\text{area}(ABCD_2) = \frac{37}{2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\;\;\;\;\\[6pt]
\implies\; &{\small{-\frac{1}{2}}}\left(7k + 30\right) =\frac{37}{2}\qquad\qquad\qquad\\[6pt]
\implies\; &k = -\frac{67}{7}\\[6pt]
\implies\;&D_2 = \left(-1,-\frac{67}{7}\right)
\end{align*}

Hence the sum of the two required values of $k$ is
$$1 - \frac{67}{7} = -\frac{60}{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

1. Find [$\triangle ABC$] = a known value = s, say.

[image]

2. Find p from [$\triangle D_1 CA$] = 18.5 – s. Since p is the only unknown in that equation, its value can be found.
3. Similarly, find q from [$\triangle D_2 CA$] = 18.5 + s
4. Find $p \over q$.